# Conditionally incude ansible role's variable files

Tags: ansible, ansible-role

Ordinarily I would dump variables in `roles/myrole/defaults/main.yml`. I don't need to explicitly include them - that's done for me automatically.

But let's say I need to support Debian and CentOS and have identical variables with different values. The common advice is:

```
roles/myrole/defaults/main.yml       # common defaults
roles/myrole/vars/debian.yml         # debian overrides
roles/myrole/vars/centos.yml         # centos overrides
```

And then we're supposed to "conditionally include" the correct set of variables.

*But where exactly?* In the main task, or a "main" variables file, or somewhere else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Q: *"But where exactly? In the main task, or a "main" variables file, or somewhere else?"*

In the main task, I'd say. For example

```yaml
- include_vars: "{{ item }}"
  with_first_found:
    - files:
        - "{{ ansible_distribution }}-{{ ansible_distribution_release }}.yml"
        - "{{ ansible_distribution }}.yml"
        - "{{ ansible_os_family }}.yml"
        - "default.yml"
        - "defaults.yml"
      paths: "vars"
```

---

A user can keep customized variables in `vars`. Put the defaults into the directory `vars/defaults`. This way the customized variables will survive potential updates of the role.

```yaml
# Default variables
- include_vars: "{{ item }}"
  with_first_found:
    - files:
        - "{{ ansible_distribution }}-{{ ansible_distribution_release }}.yml"
        - "{{ ansible_distribution }}.yml"
        - "{{ ansible_os_family }}.yml"
        - "default.yml"
        - "defaults.yml"
      paths: "vars/defaults"

# Custom variables
- include_vars: "{{ item }}"
  with_first_found:
    - files:
        - "{{ ansible_distribution }}-{{ ansible_distribution_release }}.yml"
        - "{{ ansible_distribution }}.yml"
        - "{{ ansible_os_family }}.yml"
        - "default.yml"
        - "defaults.yml"
      paths: "vars"
```

<sup>[available at GitHub](https://github.com/vbotka/ansible-lib/blob/master/tasks/al_include_os_vars_path.yml)</sup>

Comment: I was going to do something simple like `when: "ansible_distribution|string == 'Ubuntu'` but your way is so much smarter. Thanks.

Comment: Two follow-ups if you don't mind? 1) Is the path `vars/defaults/` a convention? I thought I must use `vars/main/` and `defaults/main/` etc.? And 2) why do you recommend both `default.yml` and `defaults.yml`?

Comment: 1) No convention. `vars/main/` will be read automatically ["precedence 15."](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#variable-precedence-where-should-i-put-a-variable). Other files, when not included in `vars/main.yml`, or not inside directory `vars/main` must be included explicitly. 2)The inclusion of both `default.yml` and `defaults.yml` makes it more robust. Other roles, that include this task, will work with any one of them, i.e. such a role won't crash if you by mistake name the file `default.yml` instead of  `defaults.yml` or vice-versa.

Comment: I assume you mean that both `default.yml` and `defaults.yml` are commonly used - that's good to know. Thanks again.